# how to use error values in return function with their names React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react and I have faced a problem, I want to use the state variable with names and names are similar to inputs names
here in my **app.js** code

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.png";
import vector from "./Vector.png";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const inputFile = useRef(null);
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState({});
  const [errorValue, setErrorValue] = useState({});

  const fileHandler = (e) => {
    setValue({
      ...inputValue,
      [e.target.name]: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
    });
  };

  const openImage = () => {
    inputFile.current.click();
  };

  const inputHandler = (e) => {
    setErrorValue({ ...errorValue, [e.target.name]: "" });
    setValue({ ...inputValue, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const inputs = [
    {
      id: "name",
      name: "name",
      type: "text",
      value: inputValue.name || "",
      placeholder: "Enter name",
    },
    {
      id: "email",
      name: "email",
      type: "email",
      placeholder: "Enter Email",
    },
    {
      id: "phone",
      name: "phone",
      type: "text",
      value: inputValue.phone || "",
      placeholder: "Enter Phone Number",
    },
    {
      id: "headquater",
      name: "headquater",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Headquater",
    },
    {
      id: "about",
      name: "about",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "About Company",
    },
  ];

  const add = async () => {
    const isEmailError = emailValidator(inputValue.email);
    const isNameError = nameValidator(inputValue.name);
    const isPhoneError = phoneValidator(inputValue.phone);
    const obj = errorValue;

    if (isEmailError) {
      obj.email = isEmailError;
    }
    if (isNameError) {
      obj.name = isNameError;
    }
    if (isPhoneError) {
      obj.phone = isPhoneError;
    }

    setErrorValue(obj);

  };

  const show = async () => {
    const obj = errorValue;
    console.log(obj);
    if (!obj.email && !obj.name && !obj.phone) {
      console.log(inputValue);
    }
  };

  const emailValidator = (text) => {
    const regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (!text) {
      return "Email Feild Required";
    } else if (!regex.test(text)) {
      return "Email not in valid format";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  const nameValidator = (text) => {
    const regex = /[^A-Za-z\s]/gi;
    if (!text) {
      return "Name Feild Required";
    } else if (regex.test(text)) {
      return "Name feild only contain alphabatic values";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  const phoneValidator = (text) => {
    const regex = /^([+]?[\s0-9]+)?(\d{3}|[(]?[0-9]+[)])?([-]?[\s]?[0-9])+$/i;
    if (!text) {
      return "Phone Feild Required";
    } else if (!regex.test(text)) {
      return "Phone feild only contain numeric values";
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="responsive">
      <div className="column-left">
        <img src={logo} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="column-right">
        <div className="center_item">
          <h1 style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Set up account</h1>
          <div className="img-center" onClick={openImage}>
            <img
              className={inputValue.image ? "fileImage" : ""}
              src={inputValue.image ? inputValue.image : vector}
              alt=""
            />
            <input
              onChange={fileHandler}
              ref={inputFile}
              className="p-text"
              type="file"
              name="image"
              id="image"
            />
            <p className={inputValue.image ? "p-text" : "file-text"}>
              Upload File
            </p>
          </div>

          {inputs.map((input, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                <input
                  {...input}
                  className="space"
                  onChange={inputHandler}
                  onBlur={add}
                />
                // here I want to show errors
              </div>
            );
          })}
          <select
            name="industory"
            id="industory"
            onChange={inputHandler}
            className="space"
          >
            <option value="">Industory</option>
            <option value="Industry 1">industory 1</option>
            <option value="Industry 2">industory 2</option>
            <option value="Industry 3">industory 3</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <select
            name="country"
            id="country"
            onChange={inputHandler}
            className="space"
          >
            <option value="">Country</option>
            <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="UK">UK</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <select
            name="state"
            id="state"
            onChange={inputHandler}
            className="space"
          >
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option value="State 1">State 1</option>
            <option value="State 2">State 2</option>
            <option value="State 3">State 3</option>
          </select>
          <br />

          <button className="space" onClick={show}>
            Countinue
          </button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <p className="p-text">
            Copyright 2022 Collage Nll. All right Reserved
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

All things perfect `input.name` show inputs name perfectly(in console) but `errorValue.input.name`
throw an error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')**
Thanks in Advance to all of those who reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I solved it

just add `errorValue[input.name]` to get specific error name value

```
{inputs.map((input, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>
       <input
          {...input}
          className="space"
          onChange={inputHandler}
          onBlur={add}
        />
        <span>{errorValue[input.name]}</span>
     </div>
   );
 })}
```